# $\{x^n\}$ in $C[0,1]$

Tags: metric-spaces

$\{x^n\}$ in $C[0,1]$ is Cauchy. Does it converge to zero in $c[0,1]$? I know that this sequence converge to zero in the space $L^1[0,1]$.

Comment: The pointwise limit is discontinuous, so it cannot converge in the space of continuous functions.

Comment: Yeah, I was also thinking that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point-wise limit is $0$ for  $x<1$ and $1$ for $x=1$. This limit is discontinuous. Hence the convergence cannot be uniform.